# Changing the maxDepth of viewport

Tags: c++, directx, depth-buffer, viewport

Whenever I change the `maxDepth` of the `viewport` from `1.0` to say `300.0f` (just for kicks), everything on my screen disappears. Why is that? Is there anywhere else I have to account for this change in depth i.e. rasterizer?

PS: I tried values like `2.0` and `3.0` and still nothing.

Additionally, does this mean that the `projectionMatrix` is limiting my Z values to between `0` and `1.0` if the `viewport#maxDepth = 1.0`?

Comment: you dont change the farclipp plane ( which i assume you are after ) with the Viewport. The viewports max depth is 1, since it will range from -1 -> 1 ( opengl ) and 0 -> 1 ( directX ). to change the farClipp plane, you must redefine the ProjectionMatrix.

Comment: @Tordin Again, I just wanted to clarify that I am testing stuff out - so bear with me. I am actually not using a projection matrix. In fact, I am just forcing my SV_POSITION z value. However, if the z vale is greater than or equal to 1.0f it is not visible, which makes sense since the viewport was between 0 and 1.0f. However, if I change the viewport from 0 and say 5.0f, then everything dissappears. But, in reality or logically, the 1.0 which I had forced into SV_POSITION, should still show since its between 0 and 5.0f. And that is where my question comes as stated above.

Comment: Sorry if the comment sounded harsh, not my intent. And no, it wont show, since the depthbuffer is either 0 or 1 at the moment you draw, and if you lets say, that your depth value you output is 5 then that pixel will be discarded. and thus not drawn. Thats what the depth is all about, to make sure you dont draw something thats is behind something in the wrong order. aswell as to clipp away redundant pixels.

Comment: @Tordin Its all good :-) Can i adjust the depth buffer's max Z? And what is the "w" all about? I am really confused about that and the "z"

Comment: What Api are you using? I'm assuming your going with DirectX, since you stated it goes from 0->1. This link is going through all the stages of the transformation pipeline. Might be math heavy but it=s good stuff. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418867(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Tordin I will go through that its 5:40 in the morning here and I haven't slept. Just to get the ball rolling, can I change the depth buffer maxZ to something else in DX?

Comment: I'm not entierly sure, by math you can most defenitly do it, but if the drivers will work with it im not sure. since it built in in dx drivers to handle it like that i guess. as well as precision

Comment: @Tordin "handle it like that i guess" ? What does "that" refer to?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12392/discussion-between-tordin-and-mk1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Max depth in a view port is 1, and cant be changed after that. And if the desired effect is to change the max "view distance" this should be done via a projection matrix. The Depth usage is very restrict and limited in directx where the driver takes care of most of the usage of it. so modifying it to own values will have serious consequences.

This link to msdn explenation of the transformation pipeline is good and will explain most everything about why it handles the depth for you.[MSDN LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418867%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)